# Why does pm2 fail to stop restarting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, pm2

I want my script to not automatically restart if there was an error. To only restart if it exited gracefully with exit code 0.

I created ecosystem.config.js in the script's folder and filled it with:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name   : "My script",
    script : "./index.js",
    stop_exit_codes: [2]
  }]
}
```

So that when I use `process.exit(2)`, it should stop the automatic restart.

However, it does not work and the script restarts automatically when I put this
at the top of my script.

```
console.log("test");

process.exit(2);
```

So I tried using `--stop-exit-codes` instead:

`pm2 start index.js --stop-exit-codes 2`

But pm2 gives me this error:

`error: unknown option --stop-exit-codes`

How can I get the stop exit codes feature of PM2 to work?

Doc: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/

Comment: Same here, I'm using the latest version.

Opened an issue here: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5208

Comment: This functionality was created by a PR. But unfortunately, the PR is not merged and closed. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/pull/5048.
PM2 project is poorly managed.

Answer (score -1):

Please install latest version of the library pm2, find out the latest version [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).